# OpenGL - GlVertex relative/absolute position

Tags: opengl, absolute

Imagen I have a list of 2D points (x,y) that describe a 2D terrain in my simple game.
I have then glVertex() to draw all those points in GL_POINTS mode.

Then I have a Ball that also has it's (x,y) coordinates.

I want the ball to have a definite size in relation to everything else (such as the terrain).
How should I set the values of the (x,y) coordinates to draw everything the size I want it?
Having a 600x400 screen.

I am troubled also because glVertex2f(1,1) will draw a primitive point on the upper right corner. So 1 represents to go 100% to the right or top. But the screen is 600x400 so I can't have dimensions of equal length on x and y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 0 is 0% (absolute left/bottom) and 1 is 100% (absolute right/top), you just have to find a point in between that will line up with the pixels.

For example. Say your ball is 20x20 pixels. This means that it is 5% of the screen tall and 3.33% of the screen wide. Therefore, the square surrounding your ball would have the following vertices:

```
void drawBall()
{
   glVertex2f(ball.x - (20/600)/2, ball.y - (20/400)/2);
   glVertex2f(ball.x - (20/600)/2, ball.y + (20/400)/2);
   glVertex2f(ball.x + (20/600)/2, ball.y + (20/400)/2);
   glVertex2f(ball.x + (20/600)/2, ball.y - (20/400)/2);
}
```

See how I'm dividing the width of the ball by the width of the screen to get a floating point value that works with glVertex2f? Also, ball.x and ball.y should be a floating point value between 0 and 1.

I divide these numbers by 2 because I'm assuming that (ball.x, ball.y) is the coordinate of the center of the ball, so half of the addition goes on either side of the center.

Comment: You are explaining well. But is it standard and common to do such divides all the time? 
That would be inefficient. Ëven if I defined constans Kx = 1/600 , Ky = 1/400, the notation would be simpler in the code, but I have many multiplications which are inefficient.

Comment: Then store that value (20/600) as ball.width, and (20/400) as ball.height. I was just using all of the divides so you could see where the numbers are coming from.

Comment: You could go further and store (20/600)/2 as ball.halfwidth so you don't have to divide by 2 every time. Also, please upvote+accept if this has answered your question :)

Comment: I just tried something else arasmussen ... tell me what you think.
glScalef(0.5*P, 0.5, 0.0)

Comment: I just tried something else:

'code'
P = ResY / ResX      //float number
glScalef(Scale*P, Scale, 0)
...
glVertex2f(ball.x - 10, ball.y - 10)
'code'

This lowered my fps though (because of the multiplications or the glScale().

Is this approach ok?

Comment: I think I'd stick with the method I suggested. Otherwise, you are drawing a big ball and scaling it down. Whereas with my method, you are simply drawing the ball. glScale is more for when you want to scale an objects normal size to a different size because something in your game has temporarily affected the size of your object.

Comment: yep, I think I'm ok now.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wait.
If I do a rotation, the figure deforms
(assuming the window resolution isn't a square)

'glRotatef(45,0,0,1)   //rotation using the z axis... 

how can I fix this behaviour? 
Maybe I can think about it and figure it out. But I doubt that writing that for every openGL program is a standard thing. I bet there is a simpler way. Any comments?

Comment: You're right. Use scale. However, I think you have to rotate and then scale? Might want to play with the ordering.

Comment: Also, an easier solution to all this noise is use glVertex3f. And then stuff should work with whatever screen size.

Comment: really? I'm going to try that now.

Comment: You might actually have to do a few other things. If it doesn't work, try adding this stuff to your OpenGL initialization:  glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

I'm not sure how 2D stuff really works, I've only ever worked with 3D. Also, are you doing gluPerspective() ?

Comment: And I'll still answer your question even if you don't unaccept me ;)

Comment: hahah, ok... now... it didn't work. I just added what you said. I have the following:



 // just added
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
 glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
 glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)
 glClearDepth(1.0)
 ...
        ...
 // from before
 glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
 glViewport(0, 0, resX, resY)
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
 glLoadIdentity()
 gluOrtho2D(0.0, resX, 0.0, resY)
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
 glLoadIdentity()

Comment: and I haven't rendered 3D objects before now.   Also, I want to point out that I am drawing with GL_POLYGON

Comment: Hmm. Between glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) and glLoadIdentiy(), call gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);

Comment: buu. It didn't work. 
Anyway. You don't have to worry ... I'll try to understand what is happening other day. Probably I'm missing something fundamental of how openGL works. I'll ignore those anoying rotations for now.
Thanks anayway, you helped me a lot.

Comment: You need to add `.0` after each number and `(double)` before each `int` type number (for example the first line should be `glVertex2f((double)ball.x - (20.0/600.0)/2.0, (double)ball.y - (20.0/400.0)/2.0);`) because otherwise it will only calculate using whole numbers and you will end up with a result rounded down to the closest whole number. Since the window is only between -1 and 1, the vertices will only be in a corner or in the middle if you calculate only with whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function that draws the vertices and that takes pixels in arguments:

```
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 600
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 400
void glVertex_pixels(const double x,const double y){
    glVertex2d(x * 2.0 / (double)WINDOW_WIDTH - 1.0, 1.0 - y * 2.0 / (double)WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}
```

You can also use a macro:

```
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 600
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 400
#define glVertex_pixels(x,y) glVertex2d((double)(x) * 2.0 / (double)WINDOW_WIDTH - 1.0, 1.0 - (double)(y) * 2.0 / (double)WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

No matter which of the above codes you use, the use of this function is simple. For example, the following code draws a vertex 10 pixels from the left side and 20 pixels from the top side:

```
glVertex_pixels(10,20);
```